# how to check if the variable has a same value and return it as one value in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have four variables with in a defined function.

```
def xyz():
    a_1 = self.bal.getcod1()
    a_2 = self.bal.getcod2()
    a_3 = self.bal.getcod3()
    a_4 = self.bal.getcod4()
    i =  getx(a_1)
    j =  getx(a_2)
    k =  getx(a_3)
    l =  getx(a_4)

    x = gety(a_1, i)
    y = gety(a_2,j)
    z = gety(a_3, k)
    w = gety(a_4,l)


    val = x*y*z*w
    return val
```

For eg :

Based on the return value of `getcod()` i get `2,3,2,3` as `a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4` respectively.

I dont want duplicates to pass into the four variables `i,j,k,l`
I want `2,3` to pass only once in two variables out of four variables and the rest should do nothing.

If i have all `4,4,4,4` then only one time i need to pass it to one variable out of four variables and the rest should do nothing.

If i have all `1,1,1,4`  then i need 1,4 alone to pass it to two variables out of four variables and the rest should do nothing.

so that i can avoid to return duplicate multiplied data in 'Val' variable.

Comment: Return a `set` of the values, like `return {i, j, k, l}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import numpy as np

If you want to keep the structure of your code, you could do:

```
def getx(var):
    return var+10 #Example function

def gety(var1, var2):
    return var1+var2 #Example function #2
def xyz():

    a_1 = 2 #Replace with your function
    a_2 = 3
    a_3 = 2
    a_4 = 3
    i =  getx(a_1)
    j =  getx(a_2)
    k =  getx(a_3)
    l =  getx(a_4)

    w =  gety(a_1, i)
    x =  gety(a_2, j)
    y =  gety(a_3, k)
    z =  gety(a_4, l)

    val = np.prod(list({w,x,y,z}))
    return val
```

### Explanation:

`w,x,y,z` will be `14,16,14,16` respectively. You turn that into a set using `{w,x,y,z}`, so you get only one of each different element, getting `14,16`. Then you turn that into a list, and then multiply each element of the list using `np.prod()`.

### Output:

```
224   # That is, 14*16.
```

Comment: what is np.prod() ?

Comment: `import numpy as np`

Comment: Apologies , I had one more function in between where i pass a_1 and i as a value ..like x = gety(a_1, i).. I have edited my question now, I missed to add it

Comment: Should word the same way. Replace `{i,j,k,l}` for `{w,x,y,z}`

Answer (score 1):

based on the answer above, another method:

```
from functools import reduce
```

and then add this to your `def xyz():`

```
val = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y),list({w,x,y,z}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick would be to use `set` to remove duplicates, but then you wouldn't know how many elements you got as the result, so use this to solve your problema:

```
result = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), list(set([getx(a_1), getx(a_2), getx(a_3), getx(a_4)])))
```

Working sample:

```
from functools import reduce

def getx(x):
    return x

def xyz():
    a_1 = 2
    a_2 = 3
    a_3 = 2
    a_4 = 3

    return reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), list(set([getx(a_1), getx(a_2), getx(a_3), getx(a_4)])))


print(xyz())
```

returns: 6

Comment: Appreciate the solution but i have one more function where i pass a_1 and 'i' variable as an arguments, i missed to add it. I have edited my question now.